# Como puedo conseguir dificultad en un juego Tic tac toe en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo un juego de Tic Tac toe en el cual es jugador contra maquina , para ello utilizo un algoritmo el cual hace que la "maquina" marque de manera aleatoria en los espacios disponibles(abajo incluyo el código), pero deseo agregarle dificultad al juego, ya que es muy fácil ganar

```
// funcion que simula los movimientos de otro jugador 
function turnodeO() {
    const lugareslibres = [];
    //vemos que lugares estan disponibles
    for (let i = 0; i < celdas.length; i++) {
        if (celdas[i] === null) {
            lugareslibres.push(i);
        }
    }
    //Si no queda lugar no puede hacer un movimiento
    if (lugareslibres.length === 0) {
        return;
    }
    // hace un movimiento al azar en los lugares disponibles 
    const posicionAleatoria = Math.floor(Math.random() * lugareslibres.length);
    const lugarelegido = lugareslibres[posicionAleatoria];
    celdas[lugarelegido] = "O";
    marcarTablero();//luego de poner , actualizamos el tablero
    jugadorActual = "X";
    if (esganador("O")) {//verificamos si gano 
        alert("Haz perdido !! te ha ganado O")
    } else if (empateTab()) {//verificamos si hubo un empate
        alert("Empataron");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Primero consigue que gane SIEMPRE y luego que la dificultad sea el porcentaje de probabilidad de que tire en la casilla correcta o en otra aleatoria.

Comment: Muchas gracias! No lo había pensado de esa manera.